# How to solve memory issues with Paketo buildpack used to build a spring-boot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, linode

For more context, I have a simple spring boot app which I converted to an image using `./mvnw spring-boot:build-image`. This app relies on a MySQL to function. In my linode server, I have a docker compose that pull a MYSQL image and my project image from my docker registry. The issue now is when I pull my spring app image to start the container in my linode server, I get the error

> backend  | Calculating JVM memory based on 294380K available memory
>
> backend  | For more information on this calculation, see
> https://paketo.io/docs/reference/java-reference/#memory-calculator
>
> backend  | unable to calculate memory configuration
>
> backend  | fixed memory regions require 634727K which is greater than
> 294380K available for allocation: -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=10M,
> -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=122727K, -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240M, -Xss1M * 250 threads
>
> backend  | ERROR: failed to launch: exec.d: failed to execute exec.d
> file at path
> '/layers/paketo-buildpacks_bellsoft-liberica/helper/exec.d/memory-calculator':
> exit status 1

Now I understand what and why this error is occurring, actually it is similar issue [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67593945/how-to-solve-memory-issues-with-paketo-buildpack-used-to-build-a-spring-boot-app) only it is different cloud provider. I should also say I have verified I still have more than enough memory in my linode server.

|tmpfs   |97M |97M |1% |/run
|/dev/sda|25G |19G |20%|/
|tmpfs   |485M|485M|0% |/dev/shm
|tmpfs   |5.0M|5.0M|0% |/run/lock
|tmpfs   |97M |97M |1% |/run/user/0

I do not want to write my own DockerFile for my application because it will not be as optimized as using build packs and I do not want to tune the memory calculator as it is not the a good solution as described in the link. I need help on how to solve this issue? Also below is what my build looks like in my pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <image>
            <name>docker.io/<username>/${project.artifactId}:latest</name>
          </image>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: And, according to the link you're giving, did you check this : `cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.limit_in_bytes` ?

Comment: @SebPerp I did check my memory info. I just realized when I try spinning up both sql and app image, I have this much memory below. I am not very familiar with Operating Systems but I see I do not have enough memory in my linode 1GB server
MemTotal:         992704 kB
MemFree:           71588 kB
MemAvailable:     296604 kB

Answer (score 1):

I realized after running the command `cat proc/meminfo` 1GB RAM is not enough for having a MYSQL container and my Packeto built Spring application. So I upgraded my linode CPU.